# Why 2 @Injectable memebers with the same type cannot be injected into constructor

Tags: java, jmockit

There is a class `Data` with 2 `Map<String,String>` members:

```
class Data {
    private Map<String,String> first;
    private Map<String,String> second;
    Data(Map<String,String> first, Map<String,String> second) {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }
}
```

In unit test, I intended to test on `Data` with *JMockit*:

```
public class DataTest {
    @Tested
    priavate Data data;
    @Injectable
    private Map<String,String> first;
    @Injectable
    private Map<String,String> second;
}
```

Unfortunately there will be `no constructor in tested class...` when running the test

I tried to remove one argument from the *constructor*, then the injection would work. But with two arguments both with type Map<String,String>, it will fail. Is it possible to resolve this?

Comment: How exactly it fails?

Comment: In DataTest, the 2 Injectable `first` and `second` should be injected in `data` through `Data(Map<String,String> first, Map<String,String> second)`, but it failed

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version of JMockit, Map is no longer a mockable field.  I believe you will need to create real Map classes.  So, private Map<String,String> first = new HashMap<>();

Comment: I indeed am using the old version of JMockit. and tried to mock the constructor with only one argument with type Map, and it worked